# How to set icon of an page using CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have this code:

```
<link rel="icon" href="icon.gif" />
```

Using css document?

(I would rather not have to go through and add that to every pages)
and  is it possible to set title of page using css(I am not gonna use it as all pages have different title but just for general info)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it using CSS it can only be done by inserting

```
<link rel="icon" href="icon.gif" />
```

as you have described above..
CSS is used to format some text/images etc in the page and and there is nothing to format in icon let me guess if you are working on many pages you probably have either a blog or an script to generate pages just add this line of text in it..
And you can always change icon of each page at once by just changing the icon itself...:)

Answer (score 12):

You cannot set the favicon using CSS.... You need to use a `link` tag with `rel` value of `shortcut icon`.

Inorder to set that, you need to put the below string in between the `<head>` tags..

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" /> 
                                   -----^-----
             <!--Remember to have .ico as the extension else 
                 some browsers fail to load other extensions -->
```

You need to also specify the type attribute here `type="image/x-icon"` if IE fails to load your favicon, if it loads fine, you can just ignore the `type` attribute.

Comment: I want to do this using CSS

Comment: @user2541787 Not possible using CSS

Comment: @user2541787 why only CSS? any specific reason for sticking to it only?

Comment: Not any specific reason i was actully wondering to have each and every design/confuigration of each and every page in an single css file

Comment: I forget to add in the question is it possible to set title of page using css(I am not gonna use it as all pages have different title but just for general info)

Comment: @user2541787 I am expecting mangoes on a guava tree...anyone done it earlier let me know....hey but dont draw it or genetic mutation..i know it is possible on virtuals..but can someone really tell me apart from these know possible methods, to grow it likewise :P

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a favicon from CSS - if you want to do this explicitly you have to do it in the markup as you described.

Most browsers will, however, look for a favicon.ico file on the root of the web site - so if you access http://example.com most browsers will look for http://example.com/favicon.ico automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

In href, you have to pass the image url.

Answer (score -4):

Here is the combination of combination of .ico and .gif image

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="animated_favicon1.gif">
```

Comment: This does not answer the question and is completely unrelated.